# Issue with customizing approval process in sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity, approval-process

Update--- It appears the that the workflows are completing but it is taking an hour or so to process. Has anyone encounted this before????

I have created on a list a sharepoint designer workflow that starts an approval process. Inside of the approval process that has 3 stages of approvers. The first stage is serial using 2 sharepoint groups, the second stage parallel using people from a people picker field , and a third stage that is serial using 2 sharepoint groups.

I have a drop down choice column, in the list that the workflow is running off, that I use to show the end user who is currently approving the item.I customized the "Change then Completion Conditions for this Task Process" by adding in if statements that sets the current list column to a particular value after approval.  I also customized the "change the behavior of the overall task process" to have to set list item statements. One after approve and the other after reject that updates the above list column.

The workflow is kicked off on item create. I've started testing the workflow and I have found after several times of using the approval process the workflow will not complete. Meaning the tasks are created, emails are sent out but on the very last approver in my third stage when I click approve or reject the page will refresh like it took the task outcome but the task still sits at task not started. If I try to approve or reject it again I get a message saying the task is locked.

Has anyone seen this before? Can anyone help? Does anyone know of a work around? I've been working on this for months and I need resolution.

Thanks

Comment: Lindsay, can you post an image of how the workflow looks on SP Designer ?

Comment: The forum won't allow me to upload the pics because i'm new.

Comment: Oh, its quite difficult to understand just by the information..! may be you can upload the image somewhere or email me [see my profile]..

Comment: Hi Arsalan, I sent you an email with the images

Comment: Got your email, "I have found after several times of using the approval process the workflow will not complete", what you mean by this statement?

Comment: The workflow has 5 approvers, 4 of them sharepoint groups. Tasks are assigned and completed by a member in each of the groups, but after a while when I get to the last approver ,which is a sharepoint group, I click the approve or reject button on the task and the choice is not registered. The task still says that it has not been started

Comment: can't really think of what is the problem... Can you show it on screen share? Add me on skype!

Comment: Hi Arsalan, I can't do a share screen. But would additional screen shots help?

Comment: No screenshots were enough to understand, but I think conditions are not fulfilled and the workflow remains in unstable state... was thinking to work with you doing RDP or TeamViewer!